# What is UIAlertController's handler and how do I use it?

Tags: swift, uikit, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

What `handler` does and how do I use it?

Thank you for your answers.

```
let myalert = UIAlertController(title: "Hello", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
myalert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok",
                                style: .default,
    handler: { _ in
        NSLog("The \"OK\" alert occured.")
}))
```

Comment: Read form here https://www.appcoda.com/uialertcontroller-swift-closures-enum/

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertaction/1620097-init) is pretty clear: *"A block to execute when the user selects the action. This block has no return value and takes the selected action object as its only parameter."*

Comment: which can be also written as `myalert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok",
                                style: .default) { _ in // code to be executed after the user's selection })`

Answer (score 0):

`handler` is a **completion handler**. It runs when the given `UIAlertAction` was tapped.

It has an argument of the type `UIAlertAction`, which is an instance of the action itself. In your sample code, you replaced it with an **underscore**, which indicates you are not using that argument.

Answer (score 0):

When a user taps on your "Ok" button then your **completion** `handler` will call. In the handler, you can execute the statement after click on "Ok" button, It is just like button action.

This is called [Closure.](http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com/)

Answer (score 0):

> handler{()}

It is a closure and it's very similar to blocks in objective-C. You have to write a code which you want to execute on tap of action button. In your case It will print given message on tap of OK button in UIAlertController.

Comment: What is 'coluser'?

Comment: Sorry I spelled it wrong. Its Closure. Please refer to this link. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94